# terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException Parse server

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors

I have a function called :'`fetchPosts`' that fetches data from a parse server into a `UicollectionViewController`, When i add this function to any other methods like view did appear or make a button to update the view i get '

> terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

' Not sure what's the problem here.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation
import CoreLocation
import Parse

class NewsfeedCollectionViewController : UICollectionViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate
{
    var searchController: UISearchController!
    var posts: [Post]?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let user = PFUser.current() {
            PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocation { (geopoint, error) in
                if geopoint != nil {
                    let geo = geopoint
                    user["location"] = geo
                    user.saveInBackground()
                }
            }
        }

        self.fetchPosts()
        collectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 12, left: 4, bottom: 12, right: 4)

        if let layout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? PinterestLayout {
            layout.delegate = self
        }
    }

    func fetchPosts()
    {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
            self.posts = Post.fetchPosts(viewController: self)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }



    @IBAction func reloadbtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        fetchPosts()
    }


}

extension NewsfeedCollectionViewController
{
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let posts = posts {
            return posts.count
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PostCell", for: indexPath) as! PostCollectionViewCell
        cell.post = self.posts?[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }
}

extension NewsfeedCollectionViewController : PinterestLayoutDelegate
{
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, heightForPhotoAt indexPath: IndexPath, with width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat
    {
        if let post = posts?[indexPath.item], let _ = post.image {
            let boundingRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))
//            do {
//                try postImageView.image = UIImage(data: image!.getData())
//            }
//            catch {
//
//            }
            do {
                var image: UIImage
                try image = UIImage(data: post.image!.getData())!
                let rect = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: image.size, insideRect: boundingRect)
                return rect.size.height
            }
            catch {
                return 1;
            }

        }

        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, heightForCaptionAt indexPath: IndexPath, with width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat
    {
        if let post = posts?[indexPath.item] {
            let topPadding = CGFloat(8)
            let bottomPadding = CGFloat(12)
            let captionFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
            let captionHeight = self.height(for: post.caption!, with: captionFont, width: width)
            let profileImageHeight = CGFloat(36)
            let height = topPadding + captionHeight + topPadding + profileImageHeight + bottomPadding

            return height
        }

        return 0.0
    }

    func height(for text: String, with font: UIFont, width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat
    {
        let nsstring = NSString(string: text)
        let maxHeight = CGFloat(64.0)
        let textAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName : font]
        let boundingRect = nsstring.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: width, height: maxHeight), options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: textAttributes, context: nil)
        return ceil(boundingRect.height)
    }
}

extension NewsfeedCollectionViewController : PostProtocol
{
    func didFinishFetch(posts: [Post]?)
    {
        if (posts != nil) {
            self.posts = posts
        }
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }
}
```

ANd here is the Model Post File that i use to fetch data from server :

```
import UIKit
import Parse

protocol PostProtocol: class {
    func didFinishFetch(posts: [Post]?)
}

struct Post
{
    var ID: String
    var createdBy: User
    var timeAgo: String?
    var caption: String?
//    var image: UIImage?
    var image: PFFile?
    var numberOfLikes: Int?
    var numberOfComments: Int?
    var numberOfShares: Int?

    static weak var delegate: PostProtocol?

    static func fetchPosts(viewController: PostProtocol) -> [Post]
    {
        var posts = [Post]()
        delegate = viewController

        let query = PFQuery(className: "posts");
        if let latitude = (PFUser.current()?["location"] as AnyObject).latitude {
            if let longitude = (PFUser.current()?["location"] as AnyObject).longitude {
                let geoPoint = PFGeoPoint(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
                query.whereKey("postLocation", nearGeoPoint: geoPoint, withinKilometers: 1)
            }
        }
        query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: Error?) in
            if error == nil {
                for object in objects! {
                    let pfObject = object as PFObject
                    let ID = pfObject["uuid"] as! String
                    let caption = pfObject["title"] as! String
                    let likes = pfObject["likes"] as? Int
                    let comments = pfObject["comments"] as? Int
                    let shares = pfObject["shares"] as? Int
                    let image = pfObject["pic"] as? PFFile

                    let profileImage = pfObject["ava"] as? PFFile
                    let username = pfObject["username"] as? String
                    let user = User(username: username, profileImage: profileImage);

                    let from = pfObject.createdAt
                    let now = Date()
                    let components : NSCalendar.Unit = [.second, .minute, .hour, .day, .weekOfMonth]
                    let difference = (Calendar.current as NSCalendar).components(components, from: from! as Date, to: now, options: [])
                    var timeAgo: String = ""
                    // logic what to show: seconds, minuts, hours, days or weeks
                    if difference.second! <= 0 {
                        timeAgo = "now"
                    }
                    if difference.second! > 0 && difference.minute! == 0 {
                        timeAgo = "\(difference.second!)s."
                    }
                    if difference.minute! > 0 && difference.hour! == 0 {
                        timeAgo = "\(difference.minute!)m."
                    }
                    if difference.hour! > 0 && difference.day! == 0 {
                        timeAgo = "\(difference.hour!)h."
                    }
                    if difference.day! > 0 && difference.weekOfMonth! == 0 {
                        timeAgo = "\(difference.day!)d."
                    }
                    if difference.weekOfMonth! > 0 {
                        timeAgo = "\(difference.weekOfMonth!)w."
                    }

                    let post = Post(ID: ID, createdBy: user, timeAgo: timeAgo, caption: caption, image: image, numberOfLikes: likes, numberOfComments: comments, numberOfShares: shares)
                    posts.append(post);
                }
                delegate?.didFinishFetch(posts: posts)
            }
        }


        return posts
    }
}

struct User
{
    var username: String?
    var profileImage: PFFile?
}
```

Comment: 1) Can you provide code of getData() method of UIImage? Looks like it's a method from the UIImage extension. 2) Why do you call this: try image = UIImage(data: post.image!.getData())! instead of using just  post.image?

Comment: I tried image post.image but i get error cannot convert type image to type PFFile.   open func getData() throws -> Data

    
    /**
     This method is like `-getData` but avoids ever holding the entire `PFFile` contents in memory at once.
    
     @param error Pointer to an `NSError` that will be set if necessary.
    
     @return A stream containing the data. Returns nil if there was an error in
     fetching.
     */

Comment: try to check if data is available and print exception error: if post.image?.isDataAvailable {
                var image: UIImage?
                do {
                    let data = try post.image?.getData()
                    image = UIImage(data: data)
                } catch  {
                    print("an error occured: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }

Comment: I've done that but i still got the same error!, The thing is the function 'fetchPosts' works correctly when i use it for ViewDidLoad and it actually loads the post on CollectionVIew, but i get this error when i try to reuse in any other method.

Comment: Can you provide the error description?

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UICollectionView received layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist: <NSIndexPath: 0x60800002aac0> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}'
*** First throw call stack:
(

Comment: seems like self.posts mutated in different thread without reloading collection view first. Try: extension NewsfeedCollectionViewController : PostProtocol
{  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    func didFinishFetch(posts: [Post]?)
    {
        if (posts != nil) {
            self.posts = posts
        }
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    } }
}

Comment: Tried it but still no look

Comment: I also tried : collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()  but still didn't work